# Jquery Chrome ajax post inside success function not submit form

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have a form with several Checkbox Input before i send this,
i open a jquery UI Dialog window.

if the user click the "yes" button a Ajax post is submitted, after success/done() function i try to send the form with the Checkbox values but submit is not fired.

Tested: IE 11, Firefox 38 worked but in Chrome/Opera submit() is not fired

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/904dw3vq/6/.

i can select the form element and Change some attributes but

```
$('#myform').submit();
```

do not work...

I found 1 or 2 nearly simialar Posts but not this Syntax.

Maybe somebody can help me with this?

Comment: Show us more code please to debug it, please. The console outputs something?

Comment: Add a submit handler to ready function and check if the handler works properly: `$('#form_kampagnen_zuweisung').on('submit', function(){
  console.log('form submit called');
});`. Also, same as you are using `.done()`, use `.fail()` too to check if something were wrong.

Comment: can you add your code for ajax?

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution with a friend, it seems done() or success() function does not work, you have to set Ajax post to async and check the statusText outside the ajax post function then the submit() work as it should

```
var my_ajaxcall = $.ajax({
            type:       "POST",
            async:      false,
            url:        '/echo/html/',
            data:       "stat=delete&preview=1&del_id_kampagne=174&custome_id_artikel_delete="+form_data,
        });

        if(my_ajaxcall['statusText'] == 'OK') $('#form_kampagnen_zuweisung').submit();
```

fiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/904dw3vq/8/
```